# Proving $a^2=b(b+c)$ if $\angle A=2\angle B$

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle ABC,$\angle A$=$2\angle B$.Prove that $a^2=b(b+c)$.
I have tried solving this problem using trigonometry. I used the sine rule to find $\cos B$. I then used the identity $\cos 2x=2*\cos^2x-1$ to compute $\cos A$. I used the cosine rule to get the following:
$a^2=b^2+c^2-\frac{a^2c}{b}+2bc$. I am clueless on what to do next. Can anyone give me some hint on how to proceed next.
I have searched for this problem in this forum but I do not understand their solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using the sine rule, we have
$$\dfrac{a}{\sin(A)} = \dfrac{b}{\sin(B)} \implies \dfrac{a}{2\sin(B)\cos(B)} = \dfrac{b}{\sin(B)} \implies \cos(B) = \dfrac{a}{2b}$$
Further, from cosine rule, we have
$$\cos(B) = \dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$$
This means
$$\dfrac{a}{2b} = \dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac} \implies a^2c = a^2b + bc^2 - b^3 \implies a^2(c-b) = b(c^2-b^2)$$
This means either $c=b$ or $a^2 = b(b+c)$

Comment: Thank you. it was a very easy and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the perfect square pattern from your current result
\begin{align}
a^2 &= b^2 + 2bc + c^2 - \frac{a^2 c}{b}\\
a^2b &= (b + c)^2b - a^2c\\
a^2(b + c) &= (b + c)^2b\\
a^2 &= (b+c)b
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $\angle{ABC}=\theta$.

By the law of sines, we have
$$\frac{b}{\sin\theta}=\frac{a}{\sin(2\theta)}\tag1$$and
$$\frac{b}{\sin\theta}=\frac{c}{\sin(180^\circ-3\theta)}=\frac{c}{\sin(3\theta)}\tag2$$

From $(1)$, 
$$a=2b\cos\theta\tag3$$
From $(2)$,
$$c=b(3-4\sin^2\theta)\tag4$$

From $(3)(4)$,
$$c=b(3-4(1-\cos^2\theta))=b\left(3-4\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{2b}\right)^2\right)\right),$$
i.e.
$$a^2=b(b+c).$$